# Syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body at fmt.Println(words, length)

Tags: go

I have the following in the interpreter in the tour of go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var someString = "one    two   three four "

var words = strings.Fields(someString)

var length = len(words)

fmt.Println(words, length)
```

I get

```
tmp/sandbox216066597/main.go:11: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

I recently corrected it by using `var` instead of `:=` short syntax outside of any functions, but the error is the same as before.

Comment: You must add a `main()` function, that is the entry point of your program. You have to move your `fmt.Println()` into this `main()` function. Read [Spec: Program execution](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution). If you're new to Go, first please take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1). You won't magically guess the Go syntax.

Comment: I'm in a tour of go, as was stated in the question. That worked, phrase as an answer if you want and I'll accept

Comment: You're right, I missed that part of your question.

Comment: Thank you icza, let's please not make the go community a hostile and arrogant group of "wizards" like python became before I left it..

Comment: Because when you wanna slow down and retire, and you can't find anyone to hire so you can get some rest, because nobody wants to deal with arrogant developers so they changed careers, now you'll know why...

Comment: Great, the go tools are worse than the python tools. Why would you not be able to print outside of a function is a better question? Who has ever seen a language you can't just print some text in normal execution?

Comment: @codyc4321: outside of a function _isn't_ normal execution. Most (C-style) compiled languages are like this.

Comment: Hmm, that's reasonable. I'd still like mr. kien to explain what I should do to avoid offending him if I'm already doing the tour of go and halfway done, don't mind doing it more times after this, and if he could please alert me to where he's working so I can avoid applying there would be awesome

Comment: @codyc4321: you can usually just ignore throw away comments like that, especially from (though I hate to say it) low-rep accounts. Just keep rolling through the documentation and tutorials, even more  than once, and it will all start to make sense.

Comment: Thanks Jim. These guys are no ruder than your average python dev lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue isn't with the variable declarations, it's with the fmt.Println line. You must move this inside of a function:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(words, length)
}
```

GoPlay here:
https://play.golang.org/p/JhUnNEIxIY

Comment: thank you for being polite. i'll accept when it lets me